# How to stop a process in Express when the request timeouts?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, timeout

How to stop a process in Express when the request timeouts?

install 'connect-timeout'
`import timeout from 'connect-timeout';`

```
// halt_on_timeout.js

module.exports = function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.timedout) next();
};
```

expensive process takes longer than 30 seconds
the route timesouts, but the `expensive_long_operation` never stops running..

```
route.post(
  'upload_alot_of_content/'
   timeout('30s'),
   haltOnTimedout,
   async (req, res) => {
      const result = await expensive_long_operation();
      if (req.timedout) {
        next('error!')
      }
      res({....})
   })
```

Comment: What exactly is `expensive_long_operation()`.  Unless you put it in another process, how you would handle trying to cancel some asynchronous process depends entirely upon what it is and what it's waiting for that takes a long time.  If it's not asynchronous, then it will just be hogging the CPU and nothing else will get to run so you'd have to stop it internally to the long running code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to arbitrarily stop an asynchronous process in nodejs, however there are a couple options that you can implement to achieve what you want.

1. You could run the the expensive_long_operation in a forked nodejs process and then kill that process if there is timeout.
2. You could write the expensive_long_operation as an asynchronous C++ module and build in a mechanism that would allow you to break out of the operation.